# Adding KivyMD ListItem to MDList produces blank members after the first member

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to populate an MDList in my KivyMD application with custom items that extend from `BaseListItem`.  Here is my `.kv` code:

```
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0, 0, 0, 1
        Line:
            width: 2
            rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
            
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}

    ScrollView:
        id: scrollableOutput
        scroll_y: 0 # auto scroll when adding content

        MDList:
            id: list_LynisResults
```

I need a custom list item that contains three items of text, one aligned to the left, one aligned to the center, and one aligned to the right of the rectangle.  I inherited from `OneLineListItem` for the three pieces of text, which are called `TypeItem`, `CodeItem`, and `MessageItem`.  These items are then added to a class that inherits from `BaseListItem` with `add_widget()`.

```py
class TypeItem(OneLineListItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TypeItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "Suggestion"
        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = "left"

class CodeItem(OneLineListItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CodeItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = "AUTH-9328"
        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = "center"

class MessageItem(OneLineListItem):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MessageItem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_y=None

        self.ids._lbl_primary.halign = "right"

class LynisResultListItem(BaseListItem):

    lynisResult: LynisResult
    """Lynis result that is used to populate this list item."""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    def setLynisResult(self) -> None:
        self.height = 60

        type = TypeItem()
        code = CodeItem()
        message = MessageItem()

        self.add_widget(type)
        self.add_widget(code)
        self.add_widget(message)
```

I get a reference to this MDList elsewhere in my code so I can call `add_widget()` on it:

```
self._list_LynisResults   = self.ids['list_LynisResults']
self._list_LynisResults.add_widget(LynisResultListItem())
```

When I call `setLynisResult()` to add a single entry, my list produces this, as expected (except for the black line below the MDList component):

[image]

Now, when I add multiple entries to the list, they are all blank, and it looks like their text has been added to the first entry instead:

[image]

Why is this happening?  Is there another way to approach this problem of creating custom MDList components for the information I want to display?